# Javafx setImage for ImageView from another FXML-controller

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I have a class called "AdjustmentBar" that includes an imageView, a menubar and some picture editing functions (a FXML file and a controller). AdjustmentBar is loaded to another class called "ExaminationDisplayer" (also a FXML file and a controller). ExaminationDisplayer loads a few images from an online MySQL database, and I want each of these images to be displayed in a seperate imageView.

I have been able to load the AdjustmentBar into the ExaminationDisplayer, but I can't figure out how to setImage() of the imageView that is included in AdjustmentBar. I can display an image from the database in a imageview that I make specifically in the ExaminationDisplayer, and I can display a picture in the AdjustmentBar-view if I run that one seperately. I just can't get the loaded AdjustmentBar to display the image in ExaminationDisplayer.

When I run it I get a nullpointerexception error for this line of code: imgView.setImage(image), which is in the ExaminationDisplayerController:

```
public class ExaminationDisplayerController extends AdjustmentBarController {
    @FXML
    private void handlebtnFraminghamAction(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {showCardiacConditionEstimator(); }
    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorPane; 
    @FXML
    private LineChart<Number, Number> lcChart;
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis xAxis; // x-Axis is defined
    @FXML
    private NumberAxis yAxis; //y-Axis is defined

    public void initialize() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, IOException { // Loading methods in ExaminationDisplayerController
        SPECTLoad();
    }

    public void showCardiacConditionEstimator() throws IOException { // Method for displaying CardiacConditionEstimator
        Parent parent = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/CardiacConditionEstimator.fxml")); //Reference to the fxml file
        Stage stage = new Stage(); // creating a new stage 
        Scene scene = new Scene(parent); // creating a new scene for the file to be shown onto
        stage.setScene(scene); // sets the scene on the stage
        stage.show(); // Displaying the stage 
        stage.setMaximized(false); // maximizing the stage
    }

    public void SPECTLoad() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection(); 
        Connection conn = dbConn.connect(); 
        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        try {

            for (int numberOfExaminations = 0; numberOfExaminations < 3; numberOfExaminations++) {

                String[] ID = {"1111", "1112", "1113"};
                List<String> chosenExaminations = Arrays.asList(ID);
                String SQL = "SELECT `IMAGE` FROM `SPECT` WHERE `ID` = ?;";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(SQL);

                pstmt.setString(1, chosenExaminations.get(numberOfExaminations));

                ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
                    InputStream is = rs.getBinaryStream("IMAGE");
                    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(new File("SPECT_IMAGE.jpg"));

                    byte[] content = new byte[1024];
                    int size = 0;
                    while ((size = is.read(content)) != -1) { // Når inputstream er real passer den et -1 værdi og så stoppes loopet
                        os.write(content, 0, size);
                    }
                    os.close();
                    is.close();

                    Image image = new Image(new File("SPECT_IMAGE.jpg").toURI().toString(), 200, 200, true, true);

                    anchorPane.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdjustmentBar.fxml")));
                    imgView.setImage(image);
                }
            }

//}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Here is the code for AdjustmentBarController:

```
public class AdjustmentBarController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane AnchorPane;
    @FXML
    private ScrollPane ScrollPane;
    @FXML
    public ImageView imgView;
    @FXML
    private Slider contrastAdjuster;
    @FXML
    private ToggleButton btnMeasure;
    @FXML
    private Pane imgContainer;
    @FXML
    private Label txtLabel;

    @FXML
    private void btnZoomInAction(ActionEvent event) {...}

    @FXML
    private void btnZoomOutAction(ActionEvent event) {...}

    @FXML
    private void btnRotateRightAction(ActionEvent event) {...}

    @FXML
    private void btnRotateLeftAction(ActionEvent event) {...}

    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     *
     * @param url
     * @param rb
     */
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb
    ) {
        contrastAdjuster.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            double value = contrastAdjuster.getValue();
            ColorAdjust colorAdjust = new ColorAdjust();
            colorAdjust.setContrast(value);
            imgView.setEffect(colorAdjust);
        });
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if the FXML file for AdjustmentBar is relevant, but here goes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="435.0" prefWidth="435.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Multimodality.controller.AdjustmentBarController">
    <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="435.0" prefWidth="435.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <center>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="ScrollPane" pannable="true" prefHeight="435.0" prefWidth="435.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <content>
                  <Pane fx:id="imgContainer">
                     <children>
                          <ImageView fx:id="imgView" fitHeight="400.0" fitWidth="400.0" nodeOrientation="INHERIT" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" />
                        <Label fx:id="txtLabel" alignment="TOP_LEFT" layoutX="336.0" layoutY="-1.0" prefHeight="134.0" prefWidth="75.0" wrapText="true" />
                     </children>
                  </Pane>
               </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </center>
         <bottom>
            <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="435.0" spacing="8.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                      <Button fx:id="btnZoomOut" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnZoomOutAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                          <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                                  <image>
                                      <Image url="/img/icon_zoomout.png" />
                                  </image>
                              </ImageView>
                          </graphic>
                      </Button>
                      <Button fx:id="btnZoom100" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnZoom100Action" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                          <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                                  <image>
                                      <Image url="/img/icon_fit.png" />
                                  </image>
                              </ImageView>
                          </graphic>
                      </Button>
                      <Button fx:id="btnZoomIn" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnZoomInAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                          <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                                  <image>
                                      <Image url="/img/icon_zoomin.png" />
                                  </image>
                              </ImageView>
                          </graphic>
                      </Button>
                      <Button fx:id="btnRotateRight" contentDisplay="CENTER" graphicTextGap="0.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnRotateRightAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                          <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                                  <image>
                                      <Image url="/img/shape_rotate_clockwise.png" />
                                  </image>
                              </ImageView>
                          </graphic>
                      </Button>      
                      <Button fx:id="btnRotateLeft" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnRotateLeftAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                          <graphic>
                              <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                                  <image>
                                      <Image url="/img/shape_rotate_anticlockwise.png" />
                                  </image>
                              </ImageView>
                          </graphic>
                      </Button>
                  <ToggleButton fx:id="btnMeasure" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#btnMeasureAction" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="25.0">
                     <graphic>
                        <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                            <image>
                                <Image url="/img/ruler.png" />
                            </image>
                        </ImageView>
                     </graphic>
                  </ToggleButton>
                  <ImageView fitHeight="20.0" fitWidth="20.0" preserveRatio="true">
                     <image>
                        <Image url="/img/contrast.png" />
                     </image>
                     <HBox.margin>
                        <Insets left="8.0" right="-2.0" />
                     </HBox.margin>
                  </ImageView>
                      <Slider fx:id="contrastAdjuster" blockIncrement="0.1" majorTickUnit="0.5" max="1.0" min="-1.0" minorTickCount="4" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="128.0" showTickMarks="true" />
               </children>
               <BorderPane.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </BorderPane.margin>
            </HBox>
         </bottom>
      </BorderPane>
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Last but no least, here is the nullPointerException I get if I run the code:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Multimodality.controller.ExaminationDisplayerController.SPECTLoad(ExaminationDisplayerController.java:224)
    at Multimodality.controller.ExaminationDisplayerController.initialize(ExaminationDisplayerController.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at Multimodality.controller.ExaminationOverviewController.showExaminationDisplayer(ExaminationOverviewController.java:352)
    at Multimodality.controller.ExaminationOverviewController.btnChooseExaminationsAction(ExaminationOverviewController.java:341)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 52.909 secs
```

I hope some of you can help me! Thank you in advance :-)

Comment: Two statements confuse me - "AdjustmentBar is loaded to another class called "ExaminationDisplayer" and "I have been able to load the AdjustmentBar into the ExaminationDisplayer"? Also, I can see that your ExaminationDisplayerController extends AdjustmentBarController but it doesn't seem right. Can you throw some light on what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Hi! Yes, the ExaminationDisplayer loads pictures from a database and should display them in an imageView. However, I don't want it to be just a regular ImageView, rather it should be the one I have designed in AdjustmentBar - because that one also has a tool-bar which allows me the zoom / rotate / adjust the contrast for each ImageView.  I wasn't able to call for imgView (which is the fixID of the ImageView of AdjustmentBar) unless I added the "extend" command - but maybe that's not right at all. 

I hope this makes sense! I've also added the Error I get to the post. :-)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha That is, I have a FXML file called ExaminationDisplayer that loads/opens/displays another FXML file called AdjustmentBar. How many AdjustmentBar-ImageViews will be loaded is dependent on how many pictures I want to display at a time. It could be only one, but usually it will be three or four.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Oh sorry, one explanation more. What I meant by "I have been able to load the AdjustmentBar into the ExaminationDisplayer" is that I  can open one AdjustmentBar in ExaminationDisplayer. It shows where the picture should be, and the toolbar is there and I can see that the different functions work (for example if I zoom in). The only thing I can't do is load the image to the imgView.

Comment: This just isn't how inheritance works. Inheritance is a relationship between classes. When you do `class AdjustmentBarController { private ImageView imgView; }` it means that every `AdjustmentBarController` *instance* has a field called `imgView`. When you write `ExaminationDisplayerController extends AdjustmentBarController`, it means that every `ExaminationDisplayerController` instance is also an instance of `AdjustmentBarController` (which doesn't make sense), and consequently every `ExaminationDisplayerController` instance also has a `imgView` field. (1/2)

Comment: But that doesn't mean that the `imgView` field in one instance is somehow set to the same *value* as the `imgView` field in a different instance. You have two controllers here: one is an instance of `ExaminationDisplayerController`, one is an instance of `AdjustmentBarController`. The way you have it (again, this doesn't make sense), each one has its own `imgView` field. Just because that field is set to a non-null value in one instance doesn't somehow make it non-null in the other instance. (2/2)

Comment: @James_D That makes sense, thanks for clearing that up for me! :-) I didn't realize "extends" was a type of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you have a requirement and you need to make your controls `public`, it is a code smell. Never expose your UI nodes.

The best way to do this would be to add a method in the `AdjustmentBarController` to accept an Image. This method would then set this image in the ImageView defined in the controller.

```
public class AdjustmentBarController {

    ...

    @FXML
    private ImageView imgView;
    ...
    public void setImage(Image image) {
        imgView.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

Now, once this is done. Do not extend the `ExaminationDisplayerController` from `AdjustmentBarController`.

For every image that you load in the `ExaminationDisplayerController`, load the FXML file for `AdjustmentBar`, fetch the controller from the FXMLLoader and set the image in the controller.

```
// Do not extend from AdjustmentBarController
public class ExaminationDisplayerController {

    ...

    public void SPECTLoad() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
        DBConnection dbConn = new DBConnection(); 
        ...
        Image image = new Image(new File("SPECT_IMAGE.jpg").toURI().toString(), 200, 200, true, true);
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/fxml/AdjustmentBar.fxml"));
        AnchorPane anchorPaneFromAdjustmentBar = loader.load();
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(anchorPaneFromAdjustmentBar);
        // Get the controller from the FXMLLoader
        AdjustmentBarController controller = (AdjustmentBarController) loader.getController();
        // Set the image
        controller.setImage(image);
        ...
    }
}
```

For more information, go through:

- [JavaFX : Pass parameters while instantiating controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814258/javafx-pass-parameters-while-instantiating-controller-class) (specific to your use-case)
- [Passing Parameters JavaFX FXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml/14190310#14190310) (general approach)

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! I have tried loading an existing image-file from my project with your code and that works perfectly. But unfortunately I still can't display the SPECT_IMAGE.jpg. I think that must be because of something else, so I'm gonna do a little research for what might be wrong. Thank you again!

Comment: Feel free to ask any additionally questions in the comments below once you are done with your research.

Comment: @Heidi image has [error](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#errorProperty) and [exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#exceptionProperty) properties, try adding listeners to them or querying them to see if there was an image loading error.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I just needed to add the "i" to the path of the image - typical beginners mistake :-)              Image image = new Image(new File(i + "SPECT_IMAGE.jpg").toURI().toString());