# JavaFX: what is the proper way to inject a service in a controller of a simple desktop application?

Tags: java, javafx, dependency-injection

I'm writing a simple desktop JavaFX application, which has a service to retrieve `Person` objects:

```
import model.entities.Person;

public class PersonService {

    public List<Person> findAll() {
        (...)
    }
}
```

Then I'm writing a JavaFX controller which depends on `PersonService`, and I'd like to implement a simple dependency injection mechanism to make things decoupled:

```
import model.services.PersonService;

public class PersonDetailsController {

    private PersonService personService;

    public PersonDetailsController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }

    (...)
```

However, as the JavaFX application doesn't need me to explicitly instantiate the controllers, I don't know how I could provide a `PersonService` instance to my `PersonDetailsController`. So what is the proper way to inject a service instance to my desktop JavaFX application?

Comment: Java uses the service provider mechanism for that.  You would load your service with `private PersonService personService = ServiceLoader.load(PersonService.class).iterator().next();`.  How you make PersonService implementations available will depend on whether your program is a Java module.

Comment: These may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14187963/passing-parameters-javafx-fxml and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814258/javafx-pass-parameters-while-instantiating-controller-class