# FxmlLoader.load() is not working and I have no Idea why. What should I do?

Tags: java, maven, javafx, fxmlloader

fxmlLoader.load() doesn't work; Error below.
There seems to be something about an init method in the error however I have no clue what that is referring to.
Windows 10; IntelliJ; SDK 11;

```
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load()); //This is line 21
            stage.setTitle("String Checker");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
//        HelloController.readFile();
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() throws Exception {
        super.stop();
    }
}
```

```
"C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto\jdk11.0.15_9\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1\lib\idea_rt.jar=62142:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.1\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11.0.2\javafx-controls-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11.0.2\javafx-graphics-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11.0.2\javafx-base-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11.0.2\javafx-fxml-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\11.0.2\javafx-web-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11.0.2\javafx-media-11.0.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\annotations\13.0\annotations-13.0.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.5.10\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.10.jar -p "C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl-gameplay\11.17\fxgl-gameplay-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-core\12.3.0\ikonli-core-12.3.0.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\dlsc\formsfx\formsfx-core\11.3.2\formsfx-core-11.3.2.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-base\11.0.2\javafx-base-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-web\11.0.2\javafx-web-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\zombkiin\Java\L1 Projects\StringChecker\target\classes;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-fxml\11.0.2\javafx-fxml-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.12.1\jackson-annotations-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\gluonhq\attach\storage\4.0.9\storage-4.0.9.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-databind\2.12.1\jackson-databind-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-controls\11.0.2\javafx-controls-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\net\synedra\validatorfx\0.2.1\validatorfx-0.2.1.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.12.1\jackson-core-2.12.1.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\gluonhq\attach\lifecycle\4.0.9\lifecycle-4.0.9.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl-scene\11.17\fxgl-scene-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl\11.17\fxgl-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\controlsfx\controlsfx\11.1.1\controlsfx-11.1.1.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-graphics\11.0.2\javafx-graphics-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\openjfx\javafx-media\11.0.2\javafx-media-11.0.2-win.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\ikonli\ikonli-javafx\12.3.0\ikonli-javafx-12.3.0.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl-core\11.17\fxgl-core-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl-entity\11.17\fxgl-entity-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\eu\hansolo\tilesfx\11.48\tilesfx-11.48.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\gluonhq\attach\audio\4.0.9\audio-4.0.9.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\github\almasb\fxgl-io\11.17\fxgl-io-11.17.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.5.10\kotlin-stdlib-1.5.10-modular.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\com\gluonhq\attach\util\4.0.9\util-4.0.9.jar;C:\Users\tommy\.m2\repository\org\kordamp\bootstrapfx\bootstrapfx-core\0.4.0\bootstrapfx-core-0.4.0.jar" -m com.stringchecker.stringchecker/com.stringchecker.stringchecker.HelloApplication
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/zombkiin/Java/L1%20Projects/StringChecker/target/classes/com/stringchecker/stringchecker/hello-view.fxml:8

    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2625)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$700(FXMLLoader.java:105)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:941)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:980)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:227)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:752)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2552)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)

    **at com.stringchecker.stringchecker/com.stringchecker.stringchecker.HelloApplication.start(HelloApplication.java:21)**

    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.stringchecker.stringchecker.HelloController
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:571)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:936)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.stringchecker.stringchecker.HelloController.<init>()
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
    ... 18 more
```

Comment: In addition to the duplicate, check out [JavaFX : Pass parameters while instantiating controller class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30814258/javafx-pass-parameters-while-instantiating-controller-class).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is in the stack trace you posted.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.stringchecker.stringchecker.HelloController.<init>()
at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3349)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:556)
```

`HelloController` needs a default parameterless constructor.

Comment: Or set a controller factory on the `FXMLLoader` that is capable of passing the needed arguments to the constructor.